# how to upload file to aws glacier using python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-glacier

I want to upload a zip file everyday from my local system to glacier. what is the easiest way to do this using python? I thought it was as easy as using boto3 like we have to for s3 buckets. However, the architecture for glacier is different and i am having trouble uploading it. It is a single file that needs to be pushed to the vault.

Comment: This ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-glacier-upload_archive.py.html

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear how to use boto3?

Answer (score 1):

> I thought it was as easy as using boto3 like we have to for s3 buckets.

These days it is. In the olden days glacier and S3 were separate and had different API. But these days, you can use [Glacier through S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/archive-s3-to-glacier/) storage class of Glacier. This is **much more easier** then using Glacier API directly.

So to put your local files into Glacier, you can just use [put_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) and specify `StorageClass` to `GLACIER`:

```
response = client.put_object(
    Body='filetoupload',
    Bucket='examplebucket',
    Key='objectkey',
    StorageClass='GLACIER'
)
```